# Does Android support Playlist for video files?

Tags: android, video, playlist

I have just started studying Android and I am still lost.
I would just like to ask if playlist for video files is supported in Android 2.3.3 and above?

I just found out that there is MediaStore.Audio.Playlist but no MediaStore.Video.Playlist.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yeah there is no such thing as MediaStore.Video.Playlist. And second thing is that if you want to play a list of video I strongly recommend you play them by folder (meaning you have a sort of listview that displays all of video in a folder you specified and play all of them, same as playlist). Why?

---

Because:

The point of using MediaStore is to have a convenient way to access ContentProvider which is sort of database that contains meta-data of copyright audio (tracks). If your audio is not licensed which means you are not buying the tracks from legal source, you wouldn't able to use MediaStore. So the same thing happens with videos

Comment: I think one more implementation for that is to save it to an xml file or database containing the ID for video, name of playlist etc. I don't know if it will have an effect on the performance since I haven't tried that yet and I am just a beginner in Android development. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use MX Player, it plays continuous videos also gives buttons to play next previous video in the list

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was asking for API.